# shuffle arraylist without duplicates

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, shuffle

I want to shuffle an arraylist in java but using this creates duplicates :
    `java.util.Collections.shuffle(this.OrderedCustomers);`
Here, this.OrderedCustomers is an array list.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't think this method creates duplicates, instead your `List` already contains duplicates before calling it.

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicates in this.OrderedCustomers before shuffling?

Comment: Write some code that you need to shuffle

Comment: Yes, indeed it works. I had no duplicates in my initial array but I don't know, somewhere there was something that created some dupplicates but it could not have been shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

The `Collections.shuffle` method will shuffle the elements in the given list. So if that list contains duplicates, so will the shuffled one. Add your objects to a set (assuming they implement `hashCode` and `equals`!) to remove duplicates first and then to a list and finally to the shuffle method.